# Calculate the 3d distance between point and plane, C++

Tags: c++, 3d, floating-point

I'm using:
D = |ax + by + cz + d| / |n| where n is the normal to plane; a, b, c, d are the coefficients of the equation of the plane; x, y, z are the coordinates of the point from the plane. 
To calculate the distance from a 3d point to a 3d plane. The issue that I'm having is that the distances in question are extremely small and this is causing the result( a double ) to be represented in scientific notation, which is not handled correctly in if statements. For example:

```
if( dist == 0 )
{
    //Execute this
}
```

If dist is any scientific number the code inside the if statement is executed, even though dist is not 0. My question is, is there anyway the scientific number can be converted back into fixed notation to make it usable in if statements similar to these?? 
Im using VisualStudio 2010, C++.

Comment: No.  Wrong approach. FP compares against 0 or 0.0 are obviously ureliable and you should take the absolute value of the difference and compare against some small limit.  Is there not a functional solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would use some tolerance value to compare floating-point numbers:

```
#define EPSILON (1e-6)

// dist == 0.0?
if (dist < EPSILON) {
    // ...
}
```

Or to compare to any other floating point v:

```
// dist == v?
if (fabs(dist - v) < EPSILON) {
    // ...
}
```

Sure, you have to choose EPSILON according to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`dist` is not represented in scientific notation (unless you are storing it as a string) that's just how it is printed. As another minor point, it's usually a good idea to compare to a value or the same type. `0` is an integer, `0.0` is a double.

From what I can see from some [quick tests](http://ideone.com/5Z7oTR), in order for you to be seeing `dist == 0` as true, it would actually have to be zero. That means you have all the numbers down to `DBL_MIN`, which is `2.2250738585072014e-308` for a 64 bit IEEE754 fpu. More likely your maths is wrong, and it is actually zero. Check your numerator before you do the division.

What on earth is physically that size? Well if you are specifying the diameter of an electron in units of "the diameter of the universe", then that's only [3.2×10^-42](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diameter+of+an+electron+%2F+diameter+of+the+universe). I'm not sure there is an easy way to visualize just how small doubles can be. I tried [1 / number of atoms in the universe](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2F+number+of+atoms+in+the+universe) and it still wasn't small enough.

Comment: Hmmm... [Speed of a snail / speed of light](0.03 miles per hour / lightspeed) won't cut it either. I might have to ask this as a question.

Comment: In my case I don't think the distance will ever evaluate to exactly zero unless the normal vector is 0, 0, 0. I just need to find a value small enough that can be classed as a collision between a point and a plane. Considering there is no direct relation between the size of the number and the distance this involves a lot of trial and error( 0.0000001 looks like a small number but it depends on how big 1.0 actually is )